# Problem reference converter from an external assembly

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary, mergeddictionaries

I am creating a Resource Dictionary, where I reference all my converters, so there is no need to reference each individual converter.
My converters are in the different assembly, to import them I do the following:

1. Add reference to external assembly
2. Create a Resource Dictionary
3. Add xml namespace referencing Converters assembly
4. Reference converters

So my Dictionary looks like:

```
    <ResourceDictionary xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:Client.Utilities.Converters;assembly=Client.Utilities">

    <Converters:BoolToBrushConverter x:Key="boolToBrush"/>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

However I get the following exception when trying to build:

```
Error   18  The tag 'BoolToBrushConverter' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:Client.Utilities.Converters;assembly=.Client.Utilities'. Line 12 Position 6.  C:\Resources.Tests\Resources\ResourceDictionaries\Converters\ConvertersResources.xaml   12  6   Client.eZenith.Resources.Tests
```

Any ideas why that is happening?

**Note:** From intellisense it seems that namespace for Converters assembly is correct, as all converters show up in the suggestion list after typing `<Converter:`

**Edit**: VS and blend designer both are able to find that converter, when rendering control preview.

**Edit:** I have figured out, that it is nothing to do with dictionaries being merged. The same issue appears, when adding a converter to *Window's Resources*.

Comment: Where is `BoolToBrushConverter` defined?

Comment: In the external assembly, which I am referencing. (converter is public)

Comment: namespace is: Client.Utilities.Converters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem eventually, it is merged resourcedictionary bug introduce in .NET 4.

I have fixed it by adding an empty style into the merged resource dictionary (previously I had a RD where I was merging other RD and nothing else).

[here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/MergedDictionaryPerformance.html) is a blog post which I found recently which describes the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:Client.Utilities.Converters;assembly=Client.Utilities">
```

instead.
Change: `clr-namespace` instead of `namespace`.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I haven't copied the code properly. It is already a clr-namespace